# I want to parse a .csv file and take the last line and store it in an array to then display some select values on the terminal

Tags: arrays, bash

so I am currently displaying the last line of a csv file using tail -n 1 file1.csv. That results in  the values being displayed in one line just separated by commas. I want to be able to display a few select values by doing this `echo "Value 3: $VALUES[2]"`.  So put the result of tail into an array VALUES and then be able to pick what values I want to display.

Comment: `mapfile -td, VALUES < <(tail -n 1  file1.csv); printf '%s\n' "${VALUES[@]}"`

Comment: `IFS=, read -ra VALUES < <(tail -n 1  file1.csv); printf '%s\n' "${VALUES[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

With `mapfile` which is a bash4+ feature

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -td, VALUES < <(tail -n 1  file1.csv)

for i in "${!VAlUES[@]}"; do
  echo "$i" "${VALUES[$i]}"
done
```

---

If `mapfile` is not available.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=, read -ra VALUES < <(tail -n 1  file1.csv)

for i in "${!VAlUES[@]}"; do
   echo "$i" "${VALUES[$i]}"
done
```

---

> I want to be able to display a few select values by doing this echo "Value 3: $VALUES[2]"

```
echo "Value 3: ${VALUES[2]}"
```

Comment: Is there a way to use awk and output what I want? I've seen a few examples outputting one column but can I just output the last value of that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you're asking. Also your question does not have an `awk` tag and yet you ask for an awk solution.

Comment: Update your question and add/describe what is the real goal.